# ExoPlayer video not cropping and fit

Tags: android, scale, exoplayer2.x

I use ExoPlayer library for loading videos from my server and I want to scale and crop the videos to keep their aspect ratio.
The videos playing fine and everything are fine even when I change the volume of the video.
I tried to use the setVideoScalingMode function on the SimpleExoPlayer and passed:

```
C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING
```

Nothing happens and I also tried to change the resize attribute to fill/fit.
Still no scaling and cropping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a lot of researchers all over the internet and after a lot of time debugging the exoplayer library code in order to understand why the scaling doesn't work.
I found another option for the "resizeMode" attribute via code instead of the xml option which is "RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM" and it cropped the video to maintain the ratio.
Hope it will someone who will encounter the problem.

Comment: It kinda solves it, but I still see some deformation on the video's width. It's a bit stretched up, but as soon as the video plays or I press "Back", the video width is restored to centerCrop. Is anyone aware of the reason to this deformation?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the formation occurs only after the video is fully loaded and the surface of the video changes its size.

Comment: Sorry, my problem. I was calling `mExoplayer.setVideoScalingMode(C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING)` in addition to changing the resize mode. You musn't do that.

Answer (score 3):

**Java** or **Kotlin**

```
playerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM);
```

**XML**

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/playerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:resize_mode="zoom"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In compose you can set like this:

```kotlin
    AndroidView(
        factory = { mContext ->
            StyledPlayerView(mContext).apply {
                resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM
                player = exo
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Black)
    )
```